# Ubuntu LTS boot issue

Tags: boot, raid, lts

I had to move and my server was powered off for a while. When I turned it on I had a warning that my CMOS battery died.

When trying to boot into Ubuntu I am booting into emergency mode. I've tried running `fsck` from a live CD on `/dev/sda2`, but this does not seem to be the issue. I couldn't get logs off the box, so I tried taking a photo of the fstab and the system journal

Hopefully I can recover this. I have a mdadm RAID array and worried I'm going to lose that data. I'm trying to get access, so I can back it up on my Synology.

[image]

Comment: You've provided few specifics; we don't know what Ubuntu product (Ubuntu Core Server? Ubuntu Server?) nor what release of that *unstated* product; a CMOS error messages is usually the result of machine *firmware* not the OS itself (*you gave no clues as to hardware*) and usually does not impact booting (*I saw such a message earlier today, alas was distracted before I noted it properly & normal boot occurred*), nor what clearly happened (*no clear halt messages were shown*). Pictures of text are hard to read; why provide them? Your issue, at least to me is unclear with few specifics.

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2493263

Comment: Ubuntu LTS ( cant recall version its been offline for a bit)

Apologies on the pictures being tough to read. I dont know a way to get the journal logs off the box as its in emergency mode.

Comment: LTS is rather vague; and fits at least *eight* different releases (*not counting Ubuntu Core [Server], which all come with 10 years of support*)

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Apologies as im still learning and trying my best to provide what I can to get this resolved.

If there are some specific commands I can run from emergency mode Id be more than happy to provide.

I thought the pictures (although not ideal) provided some good specifics to error messages

Comment: Replace the CMOS battery.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do would be to replace the CMOS battery.Then on the next boot, reset the date, time, and ensure the settings are all set, expecially the SATA mode and where the boot device is pointing to. Then, you could indicate if you are getting a Grub2 menu or not. If so, then which version of Grub it says it has. That would be a start.